# Grid Hub is not working

Tags: selenium-grid

I started the Hub with the following code:

`cd C:\
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role hub -port 4444`

and saved the file as BAT file and started by double clicking it. It flashes the screen and goes of. I tried entering in the cmd prompt. The following error occurred:
[image]

The Jar file is in `C:\` drive not inside any folder.

Comment: "Address already in use" - make sure there isn't another grid (or anything else) still running on port 4444

Comment: Thanks Dean Fenster for seeing my code. But i checked nothing is running before. Kindly help me to close this issue

Comment: Even if i change the port id 4445 its not running

Comment: How did you check? Run `netstat -ano` and make sure none of the ports are there.

Comment: Yes i checked with your command nothing is running in 4444

Comment: but different ports are available in the cmd port

Comment: Dean kindly help me to solve the issue

Comment: Is it `2.53.0` or `2.52.0`?

Comment: Hi Madhan i tried both

Comment: Now i tried with 5555 port its working outside the project folder. But i created folder inside the project with same port its not working

Comment: kill all java processes[`taskkill /f /im java.exe`] and try.Always use the latest version of selenium